# G.Maps javascript Multiple directions from my position. Reload page

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3, directions

Then I have the code with the geolocation of my position and a number of places where I want to go .I used the service Driving directions from google but I have a problem , I only read the first target while the others only work if I select and reload the page .
Do you have any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few issues in your code.

1. `start` is not defined when you call your `calcRoute()` function. You probably want to use `mylocation` instead.
2. You should use only 1 InfoWindow object and use the `setContent()` method to change its content (in your click event listener).